# How to revert a file in git, pulling from the index/stage?

Tags: git

Let's say I've staged a file, and then I'm working on that file and want to abandon those changes and pull the copy down from the stage again.

How do I do that?

I tried `git reset HEAD` but for some reason it unstages the file and keeps my changes in the working dir.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
git init; echo A>A; git add A; git commit -m A; echo AA>>A; git add A; echo AAA>>A
git diff A | patch -R -p1
```

There is probably an easier way, but this works.

And so there is:

```
git show :A > A
```

Even easier.  I assumed this got it from HEAD, but I was wrong there.

```
git checkout A
```

Comment: `git checkout` is the way.